# Is there anyway of converting a label to a button with href on javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I'm trying to download a document with a url that I have in JQuery. Right now I have it as a function that works with a label that when clicked it executes the href.

I've been trying to replicate the same functionality with a button without having to send the information to the backend but I don't know how can the button execute the href tag with the given url.

Code of download function with label:

```js
function downloadDoc() {
        
        if (selectedItem == null) {
            var idx = _grid.getSelectedRows();
            _dataView.getItemByIdx(idx);
            selectedItem = _dataView.rows[idx];
        }

        if (!selectedItem)
            return;
        
        var docDown = '<a href="' + _urlDown + '" target=" _blank ">Archivo</a>';
        $lblArchAdjDown.html("Descargar " + docDown);
}
```

Code of button:

```js
$btnExcelAdj.button({
     icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-calculator"
     }
}).click(downArchAdj);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is `$btnExcelAdj` to execute the `downloadDoc` function without having to use the label. Something like this:

```js
$btnExcelAdj.button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-calculator"
            }
}).click(downloadDoc);
    
function downloadDoc() {
        
        if (selectedItem == null) {
            var idx = _grid.getSelectedRows();
            _dataView.getItemByIdx(idx);
            selectedItem = _dataView.rows[idx];
        }

        if (!selectedItem)
            return;
        
        var docDown = '<a href="' + _urlDown + '" target=" _blank ">Archivo</a>';
        docDown.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can amend the `downloadDoc` function in this way which will eliminate the need of transforming a label into an anchor tag and also serve your purpose.

```
function downloadDoc() {
    
    if (selectedItem == null) {
        var idx = _grid.getSelectedRows();
        _dataView.getItemByIdx(idx);
        selectedItem = _dataView.rows[idx];
    }

    if (!selectedItem)
        return;

    window.open(_urlDown , "_blank")

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped to link the button to the function and now it opens in another tab! Do yo know how could I force the file to be downloaded instead of opening in a new tab?

Comment: Yes, you can leverage AJAX with `jQuery` or `fetch` to achieve that. Please accept and vote my answer if it helped you solve your problem.